# num_rows в MySQLi всегда 0

Tags: mysqli, php

Кто нибудь помогите, `$sql->num_rows` говорит 0, хотя когда попадает в `$id`, значение которые точно есть, всё равно говорит 0

```
  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?") or die("Ошибка #237823");
            $sql->bind_param("i", $id);
            $sql->execute() or die("Предупреждение о неудачном запросе");
            echo $sql->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ох, и накрутили )) Я ж так понимаю, что у вас первые попытки работы с PDO. Для начала: не bind_param, а **bindParam**, "or die()" - тут как мертвому примочки. В первой строке, у вас не именнованный вариант плейсхолдера ( вместо значения - "**?**"), зато ниже строка - это уже вариант с именнованным плейсхолдером. И кто вам сказал, что строка **$sql->num_rows;** что-то должна выдать?

В общем, для начала, прочитайте [вот эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/), а дальше будем разбираться.

Comment: это не PDO, это MySQli

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, хех, пардоньте )) Ну, сударь, значит в следующий раз в тегах указывайте более конкретно, а не просто "php".

С MySQLi знаком поверхностно, но все же ощущение, что надо для начала привязать результат запроса к переменной:

    $sql->execute();
    $res = $sql->get_result();
    echo $res->num_rows;

Comment: спасибо попробую, а про mysqli я даже в заголовке упомянул

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не уверен, но может быть нужно писать `$sql->num_rows()`?